# What does notation $T = \{cx \in x \in S \}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

In one of my questions set is defined by  $T = \{cx \in x \in S \}$, where $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $ c \in \mathbb{R}, c \ne 0$. I do not understand how set $T$ is defined. What does this notation mean?

Edit:
The rest of the question is: Assume that $S$ is bounded above and $c > 0$. Prove that $T$ is bounded above and $supT = c * supS$.

Thank you!

P.S. I can't find any instances of this notation in my book.

Comment: What is the rest of statement? Maybe it's a typo for $T=\{cx\mid x \in S\}$?

Comment: @md5 The rest of the question is: Assume that $S$ is bounded above and $c > 0$. Prove that $T$ is bounded above and $supT = c * supS$

Comment: So yes, I think it's just a typo. Do you understand the notation in my first comment?

Comment: @md5 Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $T=\{cs:s\in S\}$ where $S$ is bounded above and $c>0$, let $a=\sup S$. Then $a\geqslant s$ for all $s\in S$, so $ca\geqslant cs$ for all $s\in S$. Therefore $ca$ is an upper bound for $T$. If $b<ca$ is an upper bound for $T$, then $b\geqslant cs$ for all $s\in S$, so $\frac bc\geqslant s$ for all $s\in S$, hence $\frac bc$ is an upper bound for $S$. But $\frac bc<a$, contradicting the assumption that $a=\sup S$. It follows that $\sup T = c\sup S$.